# Java - How to get Next Image By Button press

Tags: java, image, button

I've managed to add an image into a JPanel in netbeans and display it.I wonder how to get to the next one,by pressing a button.

I've added the image using this code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent  evt){                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if ( result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ){
         String Ruta = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
         jTextField1.setText(Ruta);
         Icon icon = new ImageIcon(Ruta);
         jLabel2.setIcon(icon);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"You chose to open this file: " + 
                    fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());  
    } 
}
```

And when i press a button called "jButton2" to get the next image,without manually selecting it again from folder.

For example:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
     // TODO add your handling code here:       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to enumerate images in the directory you are browsing in. When the user selects the file, you should keep a list of all images from that directory in order to retrieve them when user click the next button. As well you can get the file list whenever the user clicks the next button.

Comment: No,i don't want to enumerate theme.For example : if i'm in picture folder and i select an image to view in application ,when i press next to go automatically to the next image from picture folder.Hope you understand.Thank you.

Comment: I try to understand ;) I think there is no library or framework which does that for you. I mean you have to write it yourself. Even you want to use a ready component which can load the next image for you, some one has written this phase.

Comment: This answer was useless, unbelievable it got 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this:

```
private File allFiles;
private int currentIndex;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if ( result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ){
            currentFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String Ruta = currentFile.getAbsolutePath();
            jTextField1.setText(Ruta);
            allFiles = currentFile.getParent().listFiles(); // maybe you need a filter to include image files only....

            currentIndex = indexOf(allFiles, currentFile);

           Icon icon = new ImageIcon(Ruta);
                jLabel2.setIcon(icon);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"You chose to open this file: " + fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());  
    }
```

}

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (currentIndex+1 < allFiles.length) {
        jtextField1.setText(allFiles[++currentIndex]);
    }
}

private int indexOf(File[] files, File f) {
    for (int i=0; i+1 < files.length; i++)  {
       if (files[i].equals(f)) {
          return i;
       } 
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I've tried using your code but i get some errors.For example at:

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want the next image, if possible in the same directory you chose in your first code excerpt. What you could do is that once the user has chosen the image, you could use Apache's [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to get the extension of files. If the file is a `JPG`, `JPEG`, `PNG`, etc you could load it's location in a List of strings.

This will give you a list of picture paths. You could then use the buttons to traverse the list. Once the button is pressed, you move to the next item, load the image and render it.

EDIT: This is how I would go about it step by step:

1. Create a global variable of type List.
2. Create a global variable which will act as a counter;
3. In your `jButton1ActionPerformed` method:

   - Get the parent directory of the file that the user has chosen;
   - Use Apache's `FileUtil` class to get the extension of the file names. If the file name is an image, such as `PNG`, `JPG`, etc, add it (the path of that file) to your list.
4. In you `jButton2ActionPerformed`, increment the counter (if the counter is not smaller than the size of your list, re-initialize it to 0, so as to avoid `OutOfBoundsExceptions`) and load the the file denoted by the counter using similar logic to your `jButton1ActionPerformed` method.

Comment: I sounds kind of complicated since i'm pretty new to netbeans and java.If you can guide me somehow step by step i will be very grateful.Thank You.

Comment: @TeoRoxy: I have provided a step by step guide. You should be able to find plenty of tutorials online to do what I have said there for guidance.

Comment: npinti, that wasn't a step by step guide, you're answer was very unhelpful.

Answer (score 0):

- Get the parent file if the current image (`File.getParent()`).
- Use one of the `File.list..()` methods to get the image files.
- Sort them into some order that means 'next' to the user.
- Iterate that connection until you find the current `File` then display the next one after that.